# How to get radar chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I wanted to get a radar chart using the following query. But the graph is not displayed. What is the problem?

```
 str= "{type:'column',showInLegend: true,name:'"+userdet.getCompname()+"'"
+ ",dataPoints:[{y:"+aa+",label:'self'},{y:"+r+",label:'average'},{y:"+bb+",label:'superior'}]},";       
                                   
 sb.append(str);
```

I am getting data from the the following table. "aa" is self marks, "bb" is superior marks and "r" representing the average marks. "userdet.getCompname()" will retrieve the competency name from the table report. [table report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF1Uh.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Limit 5` is for retrieving the data i.e. it will return 5 rows. I think you dont want to add any rows where there is already 5 rows inserted. You can check first the count of rows in table and after that you can add when count is less than 5.

```
SELECT count(*) from question;
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM question WHERE comp_id="+cmpid + "LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT keyword isn't allowed in an INSERT statement. It limits the number of rows returned by a query.

Your insert query is only ever going to insert 1 or 0 rows (since you only have one set of values but might hit an error if you duplicate a unique key).

If you want to limit the number of rows then you can do two queries:

1. Count the number of rows (with a SELECT)
2. Insert the new row (if the count isn't too high)

You should wrap the two queries in a transaction to avoid race conditions.

---

A cursory Google suggests that there might be database specific approaches to doing an insert if with a row count, but they will depend on whatever database server you are using (and didn't mention in the question).